# Trabalhando com vetores

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, array

Preciso gerar um vetor com 100 posições de números aleatórios e ver qual a proporção de números 2 a cada 10 posições do vetor, a primeira parte eu consegui, mas o resto não, ajuda?

```
import random as rd


v=[]

for i in range(0, 20):
    w=rd.randint(0, 3)
    v.append(w)
```

Comment: Oi! Bem, eu tenho uma pergunta: é em média a cada 10 posições ou é algo absoluto, como "do elemento 0 até o 9 tem 3 números 2; do elemento 10 ao 19 tem 7 números 2; etc"?

Comment: então @johnd você tem que se atentar para o seguinte, a função randint ela sempre vai randomizar o número toda vez que ela for chamada. então nem sempre de 0, 10 teremos a contagem de 3 números 2.

Comment: Não sei se vai te ajudar, mais já tentou fazer range(0, 100, 10) que ai o 10 ele faz a contagem de 10 em 10 e o depois w = rd.randint(0, 3). depois de pronto fazer v.count(2) pra ver quantos números dois foram gerados nesse range.